# Using JSP variable in XSLT select

Tags: java, xml, jsp, xslt, jstl

In a JSP I have the user language code (en, de, es, etc) stored in a variable. This value comes from the database.

In the other hand I have a XML file with all the values of the different languages, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<language>
    <en enable="false" />
    <de enable="false" />
</emergency>
```

I am trying to use that variable in a XSTL select but nothing that I have tried works (and I tried a lot of crazy things):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml" prefix="x" %>

<c:set var="USER_LANGUAGE" value="en" />

<c:import url="/languageData.xml" var="language" />
<x:parse xml="${language}" var="language" />

// work
// <x:if select="$language/en[@enable = 'true']">

// don't work :(
<x:if select="$language/${USER_LANGUAGE}[@enable = 'true']">
    // magic
</x:if>
```

Looks like I'm missing something, any help will be very welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Select does not accept any expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution!:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml" prefix="x" %>

<c:set var="USER_LANGUAGE" value="en" />

<c:import url="/languageData.xml" var="language" />
<x:parse xml="${language}" var="language" />

<x:if select="$language/*[name()=$pageScope:USER_LANGUAGE][@enable = 'true']">
    // magic
</x:if>
```

Hope it helps!